# How to handle multiple 'and' 'or' operators in Elastic search Querybuilder in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder

I have a POST body JSON which has one of the input as below

```
    q = (a=1 and b=2 or c=3 and d=8)
```

I need to form a querybuilder elastic query using java

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
qb1= QueryBuilders.matchQuery("a", "1");
qb2= QueryBuilders.matchQuery("b", "2");
qb3= QueryBuilders.matchQuery("c", "1");
qb4= QueryBuilders.matchQuery("d", "1");

qb.must(qb1);
qb.must(qb2);
qb.should(qb3);
qb.must(qb4);
```

Will elastic search take care of the and operation to be done first and then or to be considered.

How to I handle multiple and and or combinations (user is free to type anything ).
I am new to Elastic search would appreciate some help

Comment: Do you intend `a=1 and b=2 or c=3 and d=8` to resolve to `(a=1 and b=2) or (c=3 and d=8)`  or  `a=1 and (b=2 or c=3) and d=8`, or something else?

Comment: Assuming user intends( a=1 and b=2)  or (c=3 and d=8) , i need to take care in the design part based on what elastic search offers

Answer (score 1):

I think [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query might be helpful to you

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [
            { "must" : { "term" : { "a" : "1" } } },
            { "must" : { "term" : { "b" : "1" } } }
        ]
        "should" : [
            { "must" : { "term" : { "c" : "1" } } },
            { "must" : { "term" : { "d" : "1" } } }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sharing a pseudo code, hope it helps

```
elasticbuilder.boolQuery().should([
    elasticbuilder.boolQuery().must([
        elasticbuilder.matchQuery(1)
        elasticbuilder.matchQuery(2)    
    ])
    elasticbuilder.boolQuery().must([
        elasticbuilder.matchQuery(3)
        elasticbuilder.matchQuery(4)
    ])
])
```

Comment: `must` doesn't take an array.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just create an example query in Kibana and then 'translate' it to the Java client api.
Not sure if this applies to you but if you want to create a full text search you could provide hints to the user as per how it is in [ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#simple-query-string-syntax).

`The simple_query_string query supports the following operators:
  + signifies AND operation
  | signifies OR operation
  - negates a single token
  " wraps a number of tokens to signify a phrase for searching
  * at the end of a term signifies a prefix query
  ( and ) signify precedence
  ...`